# open external weblink from facebook app and pass facebook username

Tags: ios, facebook

I am building an IOS app that will post weblinks to facebook and other social media using social media framework (not facebook-graph-api) and it works as I desire. eg:

http://example.com/page1.html?code=123456

I do however want that when my friends on facebook open that external link and it opens in an external browser - their facebook user name gets passed on to the browser so I can allow them to add comments to the weblink.

To clarify - the comments to be added will be on my website for the page they just opened (and not the comments in facebook)

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: No, that is of course not possible. (And even if it was, it would offer no “security” at all – everyone could append any Facebook username to your URL, and then comment as that person.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do something with URL while posting it. Well if we posting URL on wall of `known user` then we can achieve your problem with following approach.

I think you can append `name of friend` as a `get parameter` in URL. So whenever your friend opens this link, its corresponding name is also passed along with URL. As far as security is concerned you can consider to append some security code to URL as well. Which will be validated against Name of friend.
For example.

```
http://facebook.com/?Name=Friend_Name&SecurityCode=Some_Unique_Code_Based_On_Friends_Name
```

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question - I've updated my post above with additional info.

Basically, the link my app posts will be one link that will be visible by all my friends on facebook. So at the time of posting I cannot include the "Friend_name" or a list of friends as I would not know who all is clicking the link.

If only Facebook app passed on the information like username of person who is clicking the external link then I can use that.

Comment: @Pankaj my understanding about your question is still same.

Comment: Added more details in my reply to your first post.